# how can I remove the submit button after its clicked on p5 dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom, p5.js

I am brand new to javascript and I am attempting to create a type your adventure game.  I am using DOM on p5.js.  I would like the submit button to disappear after you type "your heroes name."  Also, I would like the rest of the game to have a multiple choice answer type set up, so if you could also help find a starting point on that it would be very helpful.  Thank you.

```
var input, button, greeting;
var a;

function setup() {


  // create canvas
  createCanvas(710, 400);



  input = createInput();
  input.position(20, 100);

  button = createButton('submit');
  button.position(200, 150);
  button.mousePressed(greet);

  greeting = createElement('h2', 'what is the name of your hero?');
  greeting.position(20, 5);


  textAlign(CENTER)
  textSize(50);
}

function greet() {
  var name = input.value();
  greeting.html(name+' lives in a peaceful and beautiful village called Scranton.  The only village not yet completely ravaged by the chaos and war surrounding daily life everywhere else.');
  input.value('');

     text(name, 0, 0);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you are only on very beginning of thinking through the structure of this game, but here's a direct answer to your question.

Inside the greet(), you just `hide()` the input button, that's the least problem you'll have. Later you need to clear the previous messages from the canvas (in this example, for clearing the canvas I used a small `clearCanvas` function), write new ones, somehow define the next questions/tasks, give options for the user.

If you want to give a multiple choice question, my best answer right now would be - go with the buttons (until there's a proper support for radio buttons or dropdown lists in p5 - I'm just beginning with p5, but I think they don't offer those elements yet).

As you can see, I changed some background color for the canvas, so you can see better what's going on. Also, removed the `position()` calls, since they created more problem then solutions for you. When you don't use them, the elements will just be added one next to another, in relatively expectable way.

And the last thing - there's this quick & ugly solution of how you could handle the preparation and showing of your questions and offered answers, with the `prepareQuestion` function.

This solution is def. not something to aspire too, but if you're still interested in p5, it could get you going.

```
var input, button, promptText, infoText;
var canvas;
var bgcolor = 210;
var a;

function setup() {


  // create canvas
    canvas = createCanvas(710, 400);
    fill(0);
    background(bgcolor);

    infoText = createElement('blockquote');

    promptText = createElement('h2', 'what is the name of your hero?');
    //promptText.position(20, 5);

    input = createInput();
    //input.position(20, 100);

    button = createButton('submit');
    //button.position(200, 150);
    button.mousePressed(greet);

    //textAlign(LEFT)
    textSize(30);
}

function greet() {
    button.hide();

    var name = input.value();

    //  shows the greeting for a new hero, inside the canvas
    text(name+' lives in a peaceful and beautiful village called Scranton.  The only village not yet completely ravaged by the chaos and war surrounding daily life everywhere else.',  20, 0, 700, 400);

    // calls the set up of the next question
    prepareQuestion(1);

}

function prepareQuestion(questNum) {

    switch (questNum) {
        case 1:
            input.value('').hide();

            //  writes the new question for a user
            promptText.html('<p>Do you want to go left or right?</p>');

            btnLeft = createButton('Left');
            btnRight = createButton('Right');

            btnLeft.mousePressed(function() {
                clearCanvas();
                text('Going left!', 20, 30);
                // or do anything else
            });
            btnRight.mousePressed(function() {
                clearCanvas();
                text('Going right!', 20, 30);
            });
        break;

        case 2:
            //  add here the code for question 2
            break;
    }
}

function clearCanvas() {
    rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    background(bgcolor);
}
```